# How to pass foreach-object output to a function accepting pipeline input?

Tags: powershell

This is a very simple issue as far as I understand. There are plenty of similar questions on here, but I haven't been able to find exactly what I need. What am I missing?

**Expected output**

```
1 2 3
```

**Actual output (error)**

```
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:
```

**Code**

```
function processItem {
  param($item)
  Process {
    $item
  }
}

$collection = @(1,2,3)

$collection | foreach-object | processItem
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you don't have to use `Foreach-Object` here because the pipeline will directly unwrap `$items` and send one value at a time to your function `processItem`.

> [Passing Arrays to Pipeline](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/passing-arrays-to-pipeline)
>
> If a function returns more than one value, PowerShell wraps them in an array. However, if you pass the results to another function inside a pipeline, the pipeline automatically "unwraps" the array and processes one array element at a time.

The parameter `$item` in the function doesn't accept pipeline input in your code, you should use `ValueFromPipeline` like this:

```
function processItem {
  param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$item)
  Process {
    $item
  }
}
```

**Use like this:**

```
$items = @(1, 2, 3)
$items | processItem
```

Comment: I get an error `Property 'AcceptValueFromPipeline' cannot be found for type 'System.Management.Automation.CmdletBindingAttribute'`

Comment: Glad to help you :D Accept the answer so others can find it.